# execute string as variable with php's eval()

Tags: php, string, variables

What is the right way to use php's eval() function in case of the following string or what would be the right alternative on eval()
I try to build a dynamic CSV parser which assigns CSV columns to mysql table columns, inside of the fgetcsv loop. 
The documantation says that should not be used but I did not found any other alternative.

```
public function importCSV($params, $csv_file, $table) {

    if (!ini_get('safe_mode')) {
        @set_time_limit(0);
    }

    $into .='';
    $value .= '';
    foreach ($params as $param) {
        $values = explode('|', $param[value]);
        if ($param['name'] == 'Category') {
            $value .= 'get_' . $values[1] . '($data[' . $values[0] . ']),';
        } else {
            $value .= '$data[' . $values[0] . '],';
        }

        $into .= $values[1] . ',';
    }
    $value = substr($value, 0, -1);
    $into = substr($into, 0, -1);

    if (($file = fopen(JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR . '/files/' . $file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $row = 0;

        $rows = count(file(JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR . '/files/tieraerzte.csv'));
        while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            //var_dump($data[0].''.$data[1]);
            $number_columns = count($data);
            $row = $row++;
            //here data should be inserted to mysql
            //var_dump(eval('return $'.$value .','));
            eval("$value");
        }
    }

    fclose($file);
}



'$data[0],get_plz($data[1]),get_ort($data[2]),$data[3],$data[4],$data[5],$data[6],$data[7],get_bundesland($data[8])'
```

Comment: The right way of _asking_ would be describing _what problem_ you are actually trying to solve.

Comment: The right way is not to use eval

Comment: I have been refactoring the codes. I do not need to use any of the suggested. Associative array can do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$code = '$data[0],get_plz()...';

// the following line will evaluate the code and create a new indexed array
eval('$result = array(' . $code . ');');

// use the results...
echo $result[0];
echo $result[1]; //etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but there is no right way to use eval() - don't use it at all.

But you can use [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/function.call-user-func.php) to executes the functions defined in the string you've posted.
To evaluate the content of the given variables you could use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Nevertheless, everything you've pointed out leads to the asumption that you have something very wrong in your overall structure.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I know that the chosen wokaround is not the best one but I'm hanging on this issue for a while. I have been posting the funtion what I've been trying maybe you have some tips how to handle

Comment: Hmmm... explode the comma delimited string and work on each part separately. You must parse the functions and variables you get and then execute them whith the two methods I posted. Something like `call_user_func($func_name_from_string, $data[$idx_from_string]);`

Comment: thanks I already documenting myself on call_user_func(), I split my function in 2 parts and I'm going to try your suggestion

Comment: There's one use case for `eval`: building your own REPL.

Answer (score 0):

```
$elementsarr = explode(",",$string);
for ($i=0;$i<count($elementsarr);$i++) {
    eval($elementsarr[$i]);
}
```

This should work though you may want to add in some validation.

As mentioned above though eval() is bad.